# How would I convert this int to decimal format

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I can't recall ever having to do this before and the solution escapes me in C#.  say I have two values;

```
int BeforeDecimal = 50000;
int AfterDecimal = 25;
```

How would I add these two int's to equal 50000.25m?

Adding int's wouldn't work, I need to be able to say to the int 25 to shift it's decimal places when adding it to BeforeDecimal.  Also I cannot convert to a string since I need this to be a decimal.  I suppose I could hack this to a string then convert to a decimal, but that just plain wrong.

Comment: Divide by 100 and sum

Comment: var result = (decimal) BeforeDecimal + ((decimal) AfterDecimal/100)

Comment: More to the point, divide by `Math.Pow(10, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(AfterDecimal)))`

Comment: That's a nasty representation there. If it's not always meant to be two digits, how would, say, 50000.005 be stored as `BeforeDecimal` and `AfterDecimal`?

Comment: it is nasty, I'm actually using automapper for the first time and part of the example was converting two int's to a decimal, it's definitely not a practical example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just divide AfterDecimal by 100 and sum to BeforeDecimal. The only thing to be aware is the Suffix `m` (for decimal) to let the language know that you want a floating point division and not an integer division.

```
decimal result = BeforeDecimal + (AfterDecimal / 100m);
```

Answer (score 5):

If AfterDecimal will always be 2 places, you can divide by 100 and add them together.

If it won't, use

```
return (decimal)BeforeDecimal + ((decimal)AfterDecimal / (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(AfterDecimal))));
```

Comment: Considering they actually want `decimal` (e.g. they explicitly wrote `5000.25m`), you probably need a cast or two in there somewhere.

Comment: I'd use this (after adding an appropriate cast as per Joey's suggestion). I suggest adding `(decimal)` just in front of the call to `Math.Pow()`.

Comment: Answer edited to sprinkle (decimal) across hopefully sensible places, thanks for nudges.

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(BeforeDecimal) + (Convert.ToDecimal(AfterDecimal) / 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private decimal buttonOk_Click(int b, int a)
{
     return (decimal) b + ((decimal) a / 100.0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest solution, but how about:

```
decimal result = Decimal.Parse(String.Format("{0}.{1}", 
                 BeforeDecimal, AfterDecimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You will avoid possible lose of precision of `Pow`, `Ceil` and division. In addition, it doesn't care how many digits you have after *dot*.

Comment: It would also deal with the fact that if only a single digit was provided to the after decimal part. As 1/100 would be 0.01 not 0.1, which is what I believe the intention is

Comment: @DavidWatts Do you mean that it **doesn't** deal with that case?

Comment: @juharr no I mean it does. There is another edge case that it will not deal with though, and that is if you want to have `0001` after the decimal point, as you cannot have an `int` that has zeros at the start.

Comment: @DavidWatts `{1:000}` will fix that

Comment: @DavidWatts I thought that was what you were talking about.  If `AfterDecimal` is 1 then you want "0.01", not "0.1" based on the OP's requirements.

Comment: @juharr there is nothing int the OP's requeriements that states that. If after decimal value is just 1, should that 1 not just be tacked after the decimal place? All we know from the OP is that he wants `AfterDecimal` as 25 to show as `0.25`, there is no information in the question to infer how a single digit should work. Going of the information provided, my first comment still stands.

Comment: @DavidWatts You're right.  Just reread the question.  Turns out it's a little vague, thus the flood of different answers.